# knitting in RMarkdown, all of the plots print in all the pdfs instead of corresponding plot in each pdf

Tags: r, pdf, dynamic, report, r-markdown

I am trying to automate pdf reports that I have to generate every quarter or so.The following is a sample of my RMarkdown template (template.Rmd):

````
---
title: "Data Report"
output:
pdf_document:
fig_caption: no
subtitle: Quarter 4 Report
---

###This is just a sample of my code for the calculation

Figure 1. Transfers to Hospital
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=12, fig.height=6}
library(ggplot2)

Facility.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...){ #Function to create plots

# list of hospitals in data to loop over 
Facility_list <- unique(df$Facility)

# for loop to produce ggplot2 graphs 
for (i in seq_along(Facility_list)) { 

# create plot for each hospital in df 
plots1 <- ggplot(rbind(subset(df, df$Facility==Facility_list[i]), subset(df, df$Facility=="RCI Average")), aes(Date, y = get(names(df)[3]), group = Facility, colour = Facility)) + geom_point(size=4) + labs(x="", y="Number of Transfers")

print(plots1)

 }
} 

Facility.graph1(byfacility_graph_data[,1:3])

```
````

"byfacility_graph_data" is the data frame whose first 2 columns are categories (Facility and Dates) and third column contains number of transfer in the hospital. My problem is when I run the code in R (see below) to knit and create a pdf document for each hospital, all the plots appear in all of the pdfs, instead of corresponding plot per pdf.

```
# The R code for knitting the above template.Rmd script to create a pdf document for each hospital with corresponding graphs

library(knitr)

Facility_list <- unique(byfacility_graph_data$Facility)

setwd("C:\\User\\Desktop\\reports")

# create for loop to produce ggplot2 graphs 

for (i in Facility_list){
rmarkdown::render(input = "template.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document", output_file = paste0("reports", i, ".pdf", sep=''))
}
```

Comment: It does waht you are asking for... You do have a loop within the .Rmd. You need to set up a parameter in your markdown report to specify whuch facility is currently in scope and use this parameter to filter data. Have a look at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html

Comment: @EricLecoutre Thanks for your response. I was able to solve my issue by fixing my code. I didn't have to set up a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by fixing my Rmarkdown template:

````
---
title: "Data Report"
output:
pdf_document:
fig_caption: no
subtitle: Quarter 4 Report
---

###This is just a sample of my code for the calculation

Figure 1. Transfers to Hospital
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=12, fig.height=6, fig.keep='first'}

library(ggplot2)

Facility.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...){ #Function to create plots

# list of hospitals in data to loop over 
Facility_list <- unique(byfacility_graph_data$Facility)

for (i in seq_along(Facility_list)) { # for loop to produce ggplot2 graphs 

# create plot for each hospital in df 
plots1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Date, y = get(names(df)[3]), group = Facility, colour = Facility)) + geom_point(size=4) + labs(x="", y="Number of Transfers")

print(plots1)

 }
} 

Facility.graph(df) #Calling the function

```
````

### Fixed the R code as follows:

```
library(knitr)

Facility_list <- unique(byfacility_graph_data$Facility)

setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop")

for (j in unique(byfacility_graph_data$Facility)){

df<-byfacility_graph_data[which(byfacility_graph_data$Facility==j|byfacility_graph_data$Facility=="Average"), 1:3]


rmarkdown::render(input = "template.Rmd",output_format = "pdf_document", output_file = paste0("reports_ ", j, ".pdf", sep=""))
}
```

This gave me all the reports and corrects plots as desired. Thanks everyone :)